# Checking if two binary trees are identical

Tags: java, tree

Two binary trees are considered equal if they are structurally identical and the nodes have the same value.

Tree is defined as :

```
    /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 * int val;
 * TreeNode left;
 * TreeNode right;
 * TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
```

And my solution is

```
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {

    if(null == p && null == q){
        return true;
    }

    if((null == p && null != q) || (null == q && null != p)){
        return false;
    }

    if(p.val == q.val){
       return isSameTree(p.left,q.left) ? isSameTree(p.right,q.right) :false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Please suggest any improvements.

Answer (score 4):

Your code already does its job well. It can be shortened a bit:

```
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
    if (p == null || q == null) {
        return p == q;
    }

    return p.val == q.val
        && isSameTree(p.left, q.left)
        && isSameTree(p.right, q.right);
}
```

I flipped the operands of the `==` operators since having `null` in the right hand side reads more naturally.

I added spaces after the `if` and after the commas to follow the common formatting style.

Comment: `p == null && q == null` can  even be shorted to `p == q` in this case.

Comment: @RolandIllig shorter code is not always better. I could not immediately determine why the `p==q` is correct here. So I would either comment it in, or be more verbose. btw I do really like the `&&` in the return statement.